# Why MPDF library is always shrinking to single page?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using MPDF. My content of the page is dynamic. So even if the content enhances it doesn't make a page break. Rather the content shrinks and font size becomes smaller.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('default');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmldata);
$mpdf->Output($name,"D");
```

Here $htmldata is my dynamic long html variable. Here's the sample of the pdf
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztigkcdtwafh7h6/Billah%20Polin%20Resume%20%289%29.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question but could the reader be shrinking what you see to fit the viewport?

Answer (score 2):

mPDF resizes tables so that their parts fit the page.

See https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/resizing.html

Use `<table autosize="0">` to prevent most of this behaviour.